# C# Having a tough time with enumerations, have a feeling of bad code smell

Tags: c#, dictionary, generics, enums

I am having a hard time of figuring out how to do this, basically I have an application that uses enumerations for figuring out which building the person is located in, then which department they are part of.

Depending on which department the person is in, there is different groups to be added. I want to make it so that the method will only execute once until they close and re-open the app, sort of like a white list.

The problem is that Enumerations seem to be a huge pain when wanting to use a generic method.

I was able to figure out a way to do this, with a generic static dictionary but it just looks terrible and I don't know if there is something I am overlooking or a far easier way to do what I am wanting.

```
private async Task CheckWhiteList(PowerShell power, KeyValuePair<string, Enum> history)
        {
            switch ((Building)Model.BuildingSelectedIndex)
            {
                case Building.CaneRidge:
                    history = new KeyValuePair<string, Enum>(Model.UserID, (CaneRidgeSettings.Departments)Model.DepartmentSelectedIndex);
                    if (!WhiteList.Contains(history))
                    {
                        WhiteList.Add(history.Key, history.Value);
                        await power.InvokeAsync();
                    }
                    break;
                case Building.Carothers:
                    history = new KeyValuePair<string, Enum>(Model.UserID, (CarothersSettings.Departments)Model.DepartmentSelectedIndex);
                    if (!WhiteList.Contains(history))
                    {
                        WhiteList.Add(history.Key, history.Value);
                        await power.InvokeAsync();
                    }
                    break;
                case Building.CSC:
                    history = new KeyValuePair<string, Enum>(Model.UserID, (CSCSettings.Departments)Model.DepartmentSelectedIndex);
                    if (!WhiteList.Contains(history))
                    {
                        WhiteList.Add(history.Key, history.Value);
                        await power.InvokeAsync();
                    }
                    break;
                case Building.HQ:
                    history = new KeyValuePair<string, Enum>(Model.UserID, (HQSettings.Departments)Model.DepartmentSelectedIndex);
                    if (!WhiteList.Contains(history))
                    {
                        WhiteList.Add(history.Key, history.Value);
                        await power.InvokeAsync();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
```

Note that the key is their UserID, I don't want to whitelist cases where the user may have selected the wrong department, or the wrong building. This is why it must match both values.

Comment: Could you please show your "generic static dictionary" code? I was about to suggest that kind of thing as a solution, but would like to see how you've done it first.

Comment: public static Dictionary<string, Enum> WhiteList = new Dictionary<string, Enum>(); That all the Dictionary is, just using the base Enum class for the TValue

Comment: And why does that look terrible?

Comment: Because the only way to make that work is to put it in a switch statement as shown above, lots of duplicated code. I wasn't sure if there was a better way of handling a situation like this.

Comment: I've posted an answer without a switch and without any repeated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
public static Dictionary<Building, Func<int, Enum>> mySwitch = new Dictionary<Building, Func<int, Enum>>()
{
    { Building.CaneRidge, n => (CaneRidgeSettings.Departments)n },
    { Building.Carothers, n => (CarothersSettings.Departments)n },
    { Building.CSC, n => (CSCSettings.Departments)n },
    { Building.HQ, n => (HQSettings.Departments)n },
};

private async Task CheckWhiteList(PowerShell power)
{
    var history = new KeyValuePair<string, Enum>(Model.UserID, mySwitch[(Building)Model.BuildingSelectedIndex](Model.DepartmentSelectedIndex));
    if (!WhiteList.Contains(history))
    {
        WhiteList.Add(history.Key, history.Value);
        await power.InvokeAsync();
    }
}
```

If it works for you let me know and I can explain it some more. I have to run now though.

Comment: Ok, I see for the most part how that works. I suppose creating two dictionaries would be the cleanest way to handle that code.  Ill see if I can plug that in tomorrow and see if I can get that to work.  Technically I am not a programmer at my Job, just self taught and learning things as I go. Appreciate the example.

Comment: Yes this did work, this is probably the shortest way to do that. I didn't even think of using a delegate within a dictionary, thanks. This shortens the alternative by like 50+ lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

When I see repetition, I usually try pulling the code out into a helper function.

I see this pattern repeated a few times:

```
case BUILDING:
    history = new KeyValuePair<string, Enum>(Model.UserID, (DEPARTMENTSETTINGS.Departments)Model.DepartmentSelectedIndex);
    if (!WhiteList.Contains(history))
    {
        WhiteList.Add(history.Key, history.Value);
        await power.InvokeAsync();
    }
    break;
```

There are only two bits that change each time (BUILDING and
DEPARTMENTSETTINGS). So, let's pull it out into its own helper function:

```
private async Task CheckWhiteList(PowerShell power)
{
    switch ((Building)Model.BuildingSelectedIndex)
    {
        case Building.CaneRidge:
            await InvokeScriptIfNotYetWhiteListedAsync(power, Model.UserID, (CaneRidgeSettings.Departments)Model.DepartmentSelectedIndex);
            break;

        case Building.Carothers:
            await InvokeScriptIfNotYetWhiteListedAsync(power, Model.UserID, (CarothersSettings.Departments)Model.DepartmentSelectedIndex);
            break;

        case Building.CSC:
            await InvokeScriptIfNotYetWhiteListedAsync(power, Model.UserID, (CSCSettings.Departments)Model.DepartmentSelectedIndex);
            break;

        case Building.HQ:
            await InvokeScriptIfNotYetWhiteListedAsync(power, Model.UserID, (HQSettings.Departments)Model.DepartmentSelectedIndex);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

private async Task InvokeScriptIfNotYetWhiteListedAsync(PowerShell power, string userID, Enum department)
{
    var history = new KeyValuePair<string, Enum>(userID, department);
    if (!WhiteList.Contains(userID))
    {
        WhiteList.Add(history.Key, history.Value)
        await power.InvokeAsync()
    }
}
```

There's still repeated code, though. What if we pulled the call to `InvokeScriptIfNotYetWhiteListedAsync()` out of the switch?

I also see in the helper function that we're creating a `KeyValuePair` just for the call to `.Contains()`. We can instead use `.ContainsKey()` to avoid creating the `KeyValuePair` object at all.

```
private async Task CheckWhiteList(PowerShell power)
{
    Enum department;
    switch ((Building)Model.BuildingSelectedIndex)
    {
        case Building.CaneRidge:
            department = (CaneRidgeSettings.Departments)Model.DepartmentSelectedIndex;
            break;

        case Building.Carothers:
            department = (CarothersSettings.Departments)Model.DepartmentSelectedIndex;
            break;

        case Building.CSC:
            department = (CSCSettings.Departments)Model.DepartmentSelectedIndex;
            break;

        case Building.HQ:
            department = (HQSettings.Departments)Model.DepartmentSelectedIndex;
            break;

        default:
            return;
    }

    await InvokeScriptIfNotYetWhiteListedAsync(power, Model.UserID, department);
}

private async Task InvokeScriptIfNotYetWhiteListedAsync(PowerShell power, string userID, Enum department)
{
    // I find compound conditionals sometimes are easier to read if they're
    // given a name before being used.
    var alreadyWhiteListed = WhiteList.ContainsKey(userID) && WhiteList[userID] == department;
    if (!alreadyWhiteListed)
    {
        WhiteList.Add(userID, department)
        await power.InvokeAsync()
    }
}
```

Now that the switch statement is *just* selecting the right Enum value, we can also pull that out into a helper and give it a good name:

```
private async Task CheckWhiteList(PowerShell power)
{
    Enum department = GetDepartmentEnumForBuilding((Building)Model.BuildingSelectedIndex);
    await InvokeScriptIfNotYetWhiteListedAsync(power, Model.UserID, department);
}

private Enum GetDepartmentEnumForBuilding(Building building)
{
    switch (building)
    {
        case Building.CaneRidge:
            return (CaneRidgeSettings.Departments)Model.DepartmentSelectedIndex;

        case Building.Carothers:
            return (CarothersSettings.Departments)Model.DepartmentSelectedIndex;

        case Building.CSC:
            return (CSCSettings.Departments)Model.DepartmentSelectedIndex;

        case Building.HQ:
            return (HQSettings.Departments)Model.DepartmentSelectedIndex;

        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(building));
    }
}

private async Task InvokeScriptIfNotYetWhiteListedAsync(PowerShell power, string userID, Enum department)
{
    var alreadyWhiteListed = WhiteList.ContainsKey(userID) && WhiteList[userID] == department;
    if (!alreadyWhiteListed)
    {
        WhiteList.Add(userID, department)
        await power.InvokeAsync()
    }
}
```

Now there doesn't seem to be much repeated code, and each function does less work, so they may be more understandable.

There are other refactorings we could do if we didn't want to use `Enum`, but this might be good enough as-is.

Comment: Exactly this approach.

Comment: you can always refactor the code in `case` statement :) exactly what i want to suggest

Comment: Not sure why I didn’t think of making another method for each switch case. I feel dumb now.... but in regards to only filtering by the key, I actually need to check both values and not just one for the whitelist. would it be acceptable to create an object each time in this case?

Comment: In that case I would probably use `history.TryGetValue(key, out value)`, or `history.ContainsKey()` followed by testing `history[key]`. I've updated the example.